# Git usage with multiple branches

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I've been using Git for years but mostly in a single developer scenario. Now I'm working on a project with a team, and I'm not sure of the best practice for this use case:

I have a branch (call it `feature1`) I've created to add a feature to the `master`. The `feature1` branch hasn't been merged into master, but it's basically done. But I am now having to work on a new feature (which will go in a branch called `feature2`) that depends on some of the code I built in `feature1`.

Would I want to create `feature2` as a branch of `feature1`? Or should I create `feature2` as a branch of `master`, and then pull in the items I need from `feature1`?

What's the best way to handle this without causing problems down the road when both branches eventually get merged into `master`?

Comment: Must-read material: [A successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). You don't *have* to follow this exactly, but at the very least it will provide you with useful insights.

Comment: Git flow is overcomplicated and overengineered. IMHO it isn't good place to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I want to create feature2 as a branch of feature1?

Yes. Branch off of the oldest commit possible while still having all required commits that feature2 needs. (Meaning: if feature1 has 5 commits and for feature2 you need only the first 2, branch off of the 2nd.) Then you basically have feature1 and feature2 share the same ancestor, which is perfectly fine.

> Or should I create feature2 as a branch of master, and then pull in the items I need from feature1?

No, you don't want the same commit in multiple places. It sometimes happens that a commit gets changed. This would make it harder to keep track of things.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I want to create `feature2` as a branch of `feature1`? Or should I create `feature2` as a branch of `master`, and then pull in the items I need from `feature1`?

Two options:

**1. If you think `feature1` will ship before `feature2`**

You want to branch from `feature1` and this is the usual adopted method.

**2. If you think `feature2` will ship without the full `feature1`**

You want to branch from `master`, and add the commits that you need. You can also just get the code from copying it, but that's not *nice*.

**Is there a better option?**

Might not be possible in some cases but I would isolate what you need from `feature1`, possibly even merge to `master`. Consider this as the new base between `feature1` and `feature2`.

For example, image that `feature1` adds a method to an `sdk` an at the same time uses it. In `feature2` you need the `sdk` method available. In this case you would isolate the `sdk` change and then create branches from there without having to copy code or have a branch fully dependent on another.

Anyway, the smaller the change the better:
 - Create small (but useful) feature branches 
 - Open pull requests as soon as possible to have on-going reviews
 - Ask for feedback often and merge when ready

Other people might have different views, but as anything in SCM this has a bit of flavour to it.